# Not able to see build details on iTunes connect

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, app-store-connect

I am new in iOS and I upload app to iTunes connect but it does not show any details as shown in this image:

[image]

[image]

In the image iTunes not shown any information of build.

Comment: Your App Status/Info  is empty because you did not select that build for submission. In Prepare for Submission select this build.

Comment: @NaumanMalik But for internal testing it is not giving any information.

Comment: @NaumanMalik Not work for me.

Comment: how did you upload iPA to iTune connect via Application Loader or Xcode?

Comment: @NaumanMalik using Xcode.

Comment: Xcode takes time fully upload build, you can try new build with Application Loader which is faster and make sure choose the correct developer account.

Comment: @NaumanMalik I do not think that is the issue.

Answer (score 0):

After Uploading App to Store it take some time to show details even processing finished and its normal.